java and minecraft error libjvm.so
So I'm trying to play Minecraft and I keep getting this error,
Here is the log https://pastebin.com/4P3v22Xh

I fixed it. all I had to do was write this in terminal export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
